# jQuery shifting blocks of content to top on click/toggle

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have blocks of content that are toggled on/off via jQuery and I want to have the most recent one clicked to shuffle to the top of the content area.

There are 4 that can be enabled and if you do it in a random order, or even intended order, it is hard to tell which one you just opened if it's not in the view window.

Here is the page for reference http://jonrcoulter.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty simple if you use prependTo. Lets say you wanted to move the work div to the top:

```
$('#content_work').prependTo('#primary')
```

Here is the jQuery documentation about prependTo: http://api.jquery.com/prependTo/

Answer (score 0):

You could give the most recent one a specific class like `last` and dynamically reposition it.

Looking at your site however, it might just be better to hide any other open blocks and then show the one that was clicked.